# ¿Cómo puedo poner en una tabla la última columna de buttons?(Desde javascript y sin JQuery)

Tags: javascript

Tengo este Javascript, y me gustaría poner un button en `tdInfo` para ir a un Modal

```
var data;

fetch("https://api.....", {
    method: "GET",
}).then(function (response) {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
    }
    throw new Error(response.statusText);
}).then(function (json) {
    // do something with json data
    data = json;
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    // called when an error occurs anywhere in the chain
    console.log("Request failed: " + error.message);
});

var people = data.people; // Creo una var para acceder al Json
makePeopleTable();

function makePeopleTable() {    
    document.getElementById("tablePeople");
    tablePeople.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i ++) {       
        var trpeople = document.createElement("tr");
        var tdNam = document.createElement("td");
        var tdAge = document.createElement("td");
        var tdSpecies = document.createElement("td");
        var tdTeam = document.createElement("td");
        var tdSeniority = document.createElement("td");
        var tdInfo = document.createElement("td");

        tdNam.textContent = data.people[i].name;
        tdAge.textContent = data.people[i].age;
        tdSpecies.textContent = data.people[i].species;
        tdTeam.textContent = data.people[i].team;
        tdSeniority.textContent = data.people[i].seniority;
        tdInfo.textContent = data.people[i].info;

        tablePeople.appendChild(trpeople)
        trpeople.appendChild(tdNam);
        trpeople.appendChild(tdAge);
        trpeople.appendChild(tdSpecies);
        trpeople.appendChild(tdTeam);
        trpeople.appendChild(tdSeniority);
        trpeople.appendChild(tdInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: porque no creas el elemento button y lo colacas en el td con `appendChild`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

siguiendo tu codigo, intenta con esto:

```
//creas una nueva celda en la tabla
var tdBoton = document.createElement("td");
//creas el boton que necesitas
var boton = document.createElement("button");
//le agregas las propiedasdes que deseas
boton.name = 'mi_boton';
boton.id = 'id_boton';

//agregas el boton a la celda
tdBoton.appendChild(boton);
//agregas la celda a la tabla
trpeople.appendChild(tdBoton);
```

espero te sirva, me cuentas como te fue...

Comment: Me fue muy bien. Muchas gracias a los que habéis contestado

Comment: De nada bro, entonces marca la respuesta como resuelta, para que las futuras generaciones que vengan en busca de ayuda, tenga una idea mas clara. ReNiceCode